# get a integral from another

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, special-functions, gaussian-integral

> if $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^3e^{-\alpha x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2A}$ then $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^4e^{-\alpha x^2} dx=$

i tried to use integration by parts
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^4e^{-\alpha x^2} dx&=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^3 xe^{-\alpha x^2} dx\\
u=x^3&\Rightarrow du=3x^2dx\\
dv=xe^{-\alpha x^2}dx&\Rightarrow v=-\frac{1}{2\alpha}e^{-\alpha x^2}\\
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^4e^{-\alpha x^2} dx&=-\left.\frac{x^3}{2\alpha}e^{-\alpha x^2}\right|_{0}^{+\infty}+\frac{3}{2\alpha}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}dx
\end{align}$$
which appear not help much.

Comment: Are you able to find $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^3e^{-\alpha x^2}$? For the last integral, integrate by parts again, and then make a substitution so that it becomes $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx$, which is well known.

Comment: @user208259 I imagine the answer is desired in terms of $A$, not $\alpha$. The latter is easy following your suggestion. The former, not so much.

Comment: We can go for crude. Integrate $x^3e^{-\alpha x^2}$. We know the value, so we know $\alpha$. Now calculate the other integral.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I realized this too, just after writing my former comment. But then this is a bit of a trick question, in that it encourages you to try writing one integral in terms of the other instead of just evaluating each on its own. Nasty.

Comment: The natural integration by parts lowers the power of $x$ by $2$, so crude is sort of forced. Alternately, we can make the change of variable $\sqrt{\alpha} x=t$, and look up the gamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** Use integration by parts to calculate $\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx$. We know this is $\frac{1}{2A}$, so we can calculate $\alpha$.

Now use a couple of integrations by parts to calculate $\int_0^\infty x^4 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx$.

Not elegant, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{2 n} e^{-a x^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{(2 n-1) ! !}{2^{n}} a^{-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}
$$
by integration by parts , where $a>0, n \in \mathbb{N}$